# Can I make a web based video recording?

Tags: flash, video, adobe

I want to have a web site which switches the web camera of users, makes a video recording and send results to my web server.

Is it possible to do that? I think it should be. For example such sites as [chatroulette.com](http://chatroulette.com/) starts web camera. Should it be done with the Adobe Flash technologies? Is it hard to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue with video is that that it has to be encoded to a proper format. To do what you want, you would need access to a flash media server which would handle all the recording/encoding/and saving video from a webcam.

There is also the java based open source [RED5](http://osflash.org/red5) that should be able to do so.  But you will need a java enabled webhost to be able to deploy, which is not available with most basic web hosting companies.